# sql select a moving range

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with columns year and movie ids, and for each year, I want to get the count for of the ids with year within 10 years of that year.

e.g. if I had the data:
year | id
1950    1
1951    2
1960    1

I would want to return
year | count
1950    3
1951    3
1960    1

I thought I could do it like this

```
select m1.year, count(m1.id)
  from movie m1
  join movie m2
    on m1.id=m2.id
 where m2.year>=m1.year
   and m2.year<=m1.year+9
 group by m1.year
 order by m1.year;
```

but this just returns the movies in each year (or seems to, since the results are identical to select year, count(id) from movie group by year;)

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: side note: you can write `where m2.year - m1.year BETWEEN 0 AND 9`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joining on ids is not what you want: you'll get a 1<=>1 relationship most probably (May I assume `id` is a key?

```
SELECT m1.year, COUNT(*)
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT year FROM movie) m1
 CROSS JOIN movie M2
 WHERE m2.year - m1.year BETWEEN 0 AND 9
 GROUP BY m1.year
 ORDER BY m1.year
```

Comment: and yes, id is a primary key.

Comment: `CROSS JOIN` is cartesian product: you get every row of m2 for every row of m1. You can replace `CROSS JOIN` with a simple comma.

Comment: ah, I've only learned it as a comma. Now that I read it, I'm going "DUH, of course joining on ids is a bad plan". Thanks!